# Updated R, copied library, still can't find packages, and can't seem to install all dependencies

Tags: r

I updated R using `installr` and asked to copy my library. (Even though I've *never* had this work, I keep hoping maybe it will someday as the package gets updated.) Opened up RStudio and, as usual, it can't find any of the packages that were in my old library. I next copied all the files from my old library into my new library, and several critical ones still don't work. For example, when I tried to load `tidyverse`, the message I receive is:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:  package ‘lazyeval’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version.

I tried `remove.packages("tidyverse")` and then `install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)`, and I *still* get the same message about the package `lazyeval`. I tried installing `lazyeval`, but then, when I go through those same steps again to try to use `tidyverse`, now it's `lubridate` that was installed by an R version with different internals.

How can I avoid this incredibly irritating and time-sucking iterative process of trying to install a package, seeing that the internals are wrong for some dependent package, installing whatever package was the problem, installing the package I actually care about, and then figuring out what *other* dependencies are problems?

Comment: Try removing `tidyverse` and all its dependencies at once. Then you can install `tidyverse` again. You can find dependencies of `tidyverse` with `tools::package_dependencies("tidyverse", db = installed.packages())`. Then use `remove.packages()` to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tidyverse` package hardly contains anything:  its main purpose is to get a bunch of other packages loaded.  Removing it and updating it won't help update the other packages.  You could do what @phago29 suggested in their comment, but an easier way is just to update everything.  Run this command in an R session:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

A few notes:

- If you have admin capabilities, run as admin, and it will update your main library.  If you don't, it'll install new copies in your user account.
- Even though you're saying `ask = FALSE`, it may ask some questions about whether you can build packages from source.  Answer "Yes" if your system is set up to do that, "No" if not.  If you're not sure, try "Yes", and if you get install failures, run it again and say "No".)
- This is likely to run for a while, so go away and have a coffee or something.

Comment: Thanks, @user2554330, I'm trying this. It *seems* to be working. (Sorry, I had some computer troubles involving a cat and a glass of water too close to my laptop, so it took me a bit to get back to you!) I'm getting several messages like this: `Warning: package 'lazyeval' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library' will not be updated`. Why won't those get updated?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why those won't be updated, but they seem to be present nonetheless! Thank you!