# Rstudio - cannot install Tidyverse or other packages

Tags: r, install.packages

I've started to re-use R through RStudio, and I've not used it for a while. For some reason, I'm having trouble installing tidyverse and a number of other packages. In my previous experience, this was such a simple task. I just reinstalled the latest version of RStudio and it doesn't seem to help.

The problem seems to be that I have a non-zero exit, and that a lot of the dependent packages are not available. Ì get text such as the following as well.

`Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:`

```
       binary source needs_compilation
cli     1.0.0  2.0.2             FALSE
rlang   0.2.0  0.4.5              TRUE
pillar  1.2.1  1.4.3             FALSE
```

Any advice on where to start?

Comment: Definitely an error, after installing tidyverse and I type library(tidyverse), I see that there is no package called tidyverse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rtools not being detected by R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885381/rtools-not-being-detected-by-r)

Comment: I think this might be on the right path - I will have to try a few things from that thread

Comment: This question may be relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/60356442/2554330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
install.packages(c("cli", "rlang", "pillar"))
```

Comment: I think I have more that I also need to install - forcats, hms, etc. Thanks

Comment: I will do, I don't think it solves my problem yet. I still have packages that are not installed that seems to be dependencies

Comment: @BillHammond This seems to answer your question. What else do you need?